# How to separate different values in 2-d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The array has objects from different subclasses. How can I print the objects according to there subclasses?

I used scanner to read student (Graduate and Undergraduate) objects and put into an array.

I need to use inheritance and toString methods to get the results.

---

Original data in txt file:

G Steve 23 Biology

U Julia 19 Music Flute, year: Sophomore

G David 25 Math

---

### I was able to read and print the objects but only in original order:

Graduate Name:Steve, Age: 23, Major: Biology

Undergraduate Name: Julia, Age: 19, Major: Music, year: Sophomore

Graduate Name: Dvid, Age: 25, Major: Math

Below is the method I used in tester file:

---

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
Student s = new Undergraduate(type,name,age,major,year);
studentList.add(s);
Student s = new Graduate(type,name,age, major);
studentList.add(s);

for (Student d:studentList) {
System.out.println(d.toString());
}
```

===
Expected result:===

Number of Undergraduate Student: 1

Name: Julia, Age: 19, Major: Music, year: Sophomore

---

Number of Graduate Student: 2

Name:Steve, Age: 23, Major: Biology

Name:Dvid, Age: 25, Major: Math

===

This is my first question here. I am not familiar with the system. I tried to make my question easier to read. Sorry if it looks messy.

Comment: Hi. I think I understand your input and the output you are looking for. I would suggest using two `ArrayList`s and sorting the objects during loading.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried 2 arrays method but got an error after reset the scanner. The first class was listed correctly but got "java.util.NoSuchElementException" for the 2nd class.

Comment: Thanks everybody's response! I ended up use "instanceof" to complete this task because I actually have more classes and the # of attributes are different between classes.

Comment: I have a follow-up question, - how can I delete an object from the array and file according to a criteria, e.g., name and age? I read some examples using iterator but didn't follow well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use instanceof to  separate the different types of objects.
ex.

```
if (s instanceof Undergraduate){
   Undergraduate u = (Undergraduate) s;
}
```

You can iterate your list and count your objets using instanceof.
You can do the check above during the input too.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is to create two separate ArrayLists: One for Undergraduate students and one for Graduate students:

```
ArrayList<Student> undGrdStudentList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Student> grdStudentList = new ArrayList<>();
if ("U".equals(type)){
  Student s = new Undergraduate(type,name,major);
  undGrdStudentList.add(s);
}else{
  Student s = new Graduate(type,name,major);
  grdStudentList .add(s);
}

System.out.println("Number of Undergraduate Students: " + undGrdStudentList.size());
for (Student d:undGrdStudentList) {
  System.out.println(d.toString());
}

System.out.println("Number of Graduate Students: " + grdStudentList .size());
for (Student d:grdStudentList ) {
  System.out.println(d.toString());
}
```

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

```
Triple<String,Integer,String> student;
List<Triple<String,Integer,String>> UstudentList = new ArrayList<>();
student = new MutableTriple<>("jin",23,"biology");
UstudentList.add(student);
List<Triple<String,Integer,String>> GstudentList = new ArrayList<>();
student = new MutableTriple<>("amol",23,"music");
GstudentList.add(student);
```

Triple class is from `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple`

for your expected result

```
 System.out.println("No. of Undergraduate: "+UstudentList.size())
for (Triple<String,Integer,String> stud: UstudentList) {
            System.out.println(stud.getLeft()+stud.getMiddle()+stud.getRight());
        }
 System.out.println("No. of Graduate: "+GstudentList.size())
for (Triple<String,Integer,String> stud: GstudentList) {
            System.out.println(stud.getLeft()+stud.getMiddle()+stud.getRight());
        }
```

Comment: How does it help in OPs problem?

Comment: you mean OOPS ?.

Comment: I mean the authors problem.

Comment: My suggestion is why we need to create a new object like `Undergraduate`& `Student` . where predefined one like Triple will satisfy out for our problem statement

Comment: Maybe `Undergraduate` and `Student` implements others methods. In my opinion your solution is not good, it will works for this case but the readability is very bad, it's very easy to forget what values are store in the `Triple` object.

Comment: I think you've missunderstood what the problem is. The author wants to separate those two types. With your approuch you totally lose information about student type.

Comment: Yap. I misunderstood the statement he asked

Comment: @Amongalen actually he reads the original data from the txt file. so while reading it he adds it in `Undergraduate` & `Graduate` objects using the first letter so ... we can use two lists of triplets to separate it. Though it is not good design it's easy to implement it using the predefined one like `triple` instead of creating new objects