# How to search and remove an object from an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

This is a follow up question from my previous post:

[How to separate different values in 2-d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371462/how-to-separate-different-values-in-2-d-array)

I now need to delete specific object from the array according to the criteria, e.g., name and age, then save the result in file.  I have read some examples using iterator but didn't follow well.

### Original data in txt file:

```
G Steve 23 Biology 
U Julia 19 Music Flute Sophomore 
G David 25 Math
```

Below is the method I used to create the arraylist while reading the data from txt file

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
Student s = new Undergraduate(type,name,age,major,year);
studentList.add(s);
Student s = new Graduate(type,name,age, major);
studentList.add(s);

for (Student d:studentList) {
    System.out.println(d.toString());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the question, where is this multidimensional array you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry that my title may be not appropriate. It's just the array like the txt file. I have edited the title hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: Are you aware that `ArrayList` has a [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) method?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you could take the advantage of Streaming.
For example your code could look like:

```
List<Student> myFilteredList = studentList.stream()
  .filter(student -> !student.getName().equals("Julia"))
  .filter(student -> student.getAge() > 23)
  .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

If you are not used to lambda expression I think it would be a great idea to take a look into that topic.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a an object from a list you can use `removeIf` with a condition, below example removes any student older than 22 of type "G"

```
studentList.removeIf(s -> s.age > 22 && s.type.equals("G"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several methods finally got this:

```
                                System.out.println("Enter Student name: ");
                                System.out.println("Enter StudentID: ");
                                String dname = sc.next();
                                int dage = sc.nextInt();



                                for (Student s:studentList){
                                    if (s.getName().equals(dname)&&s.getAge()>dage) {
                                        System.out.println();
                                        studentList.remove(s);
                                        System.out.println("You removed: "+s.getName());
                                        System.out.println();
                                        break;
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println();
                                        System.out.println("This Student doesn't exist");
                                        System.out.println();
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
```

It runs but always says "The Student doesn't exist". Is it that the "getName" not working (I assume it calls the "name" string from the constructor in the Student class?)  Anybody can help?